# Auto not being recognised by the compiler, what would be the best replacement?

Tags: c++, variables, auto

So I have wrote a program that uses auto however the compiler doesn't seem to recognize it, probably it is an earlier compiler.

I was wondering for my code, what are suitable variables to fix my code so that I do not need to use the auto keyword? I'm thinking a pointer to a string? or a string iterator, though I am not sure.

```
  #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        enum MODE {
            WHOLE, PREFIX, SUFFIX, ANYWHERE, EMBEDDED
        } mode = WHOLE;
        bool reverse_match = false;

        int c;
        while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, ":wpsaev")) != -1) {
            switch (c) {
                case 'w': // pattern matches whole word
                    mode = WHOLE;
                    break;
                case 'p': // pattern matches prefix
                    mode = PREFIX;
                    break;
                case 'a': // pattern matches anywhere
                    mode = ANYWHERE;
                    break;
                case 's': // pattern matches suffix
                    mode = SUFFIX;
                    break;
                case 'e': // pattern matches anywhere
                    mode = EMBEDDED;
                    break;
                case 'v': // reverse sense of match
                    reverse_match = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        argc -= optind;
        argv += optind;

        string pattern = argv[0];


        string word;
        int matches = 0;

        while (cin >> word) {

            switch (mode) {
                case WHOLE:
                    if (reverse_match) {
                        if (pattern != word) {
                            matches += 1;
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                    } else if (pattern == word) {
                        matches += 1;
                        cout << word << endl;
                    }
                    break;
                case PREFIX:
                    if (pattern.size() <= word.size()) {
                        auto res = mismatch(pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), word.begin());

                        if (reverse_match) {
                            if (res.first != word.end()) {
                                matches += 1;
                                cout << word << endl;
                            }
                        } else if (res.first == word.end()) {
                            matches += 1;
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case ANYWHERE:

                    if (reverse_match) {
                        if (!word.find(pattern) != string::npos) {
                            matches += 1;
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                    } else if (word.find(pattern) != string::npos) {
                        matches += 1;
                        cout << word << endl;
                    }
                    break;
                case SUFFIX:
                    if (pattern.size() <= word.size()) {
                        auto res = mismatch(pattern.rbegin(), pattern.rend(), word.rbegin());

                        if (reverse_match) {
                            if (res.first != word.rend()) {
                                matches = +1;
                                cout << word << endl;
                            }
                        } else if (res.first == word.rend()) {
                            matches = +1;
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case EMBEDDED:
                    if (reverse_match) {
                        if (!pattern.find(word) != string::npos) {
                            matches += 1;
                            cout << word << endl;}

                    } else if (pattern.find(word) != string::npos) {
                        matches += 1;
                        cout 

<< word << endl;
                }
                break;
        }

    }
    return (matches == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Errors I get:

```
main.cpp:70:26: error: 'res' does not name a type
main.cpp:73:29: error: 'res' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:77:32: error: 'res' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:97:26: error: 'res' does not name a type 
main.cpp:100:29: error: 'res' was not declared in this scope 
main.cpp:104:32: error: 'res' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: define "the compiler doesn't seem to recognize it". How? What are you expecting it to do? which line?

Comment: There isn't a one-size replacement, One of your uses is `std::pair<std::string::iterator,std::string::iterator>`, while one would instead use `std::pair<std::string::iterator,std::string::reverse_iterator>` But I'm more curious as to why `auto` isn't doing its job. So I second chris' question. **what compiler are you using?**

Comment: Added the errors to the main post.

Comment: @user1719605 and still didn't answer the question. *Please*: What compiler are you using? (also, this is wrong: `if (!pattern.find(word) != string::npos)`, you're comparing a `bool` to a pos_type. you need some parens around the inner expression. this happens at least twice).

Comment: Sorry g++, so would `if (!(pattern.find(word) != string::npos)` work?

Comment: Closer, that won't compile as you need a matching close-paren, but the  opener is in the right place at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using auto to declare variables saving the return value of mismatch, it could be replaced with the return type of said function. According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch), this would be

```
std::pair<InputIt1,InputIt2>.
```

In your first use this would mean InputIt1=InputIt2=std::string::iterator(the return type of std::string::begin) and the result type should be 
    std::pair

In your second it would be the return type of std::string::rbegin():

```
std::pair<std::string::reverse_iterator,std::string::reverse_iterator>
```

I hope this helps, but it is of course rather tedious to enter such long typenames and auto should, imho, be prefered, so if you can use a more modern compiler(or pass the right flags to your current one(-std=c++11 for g++ for instance)), i suggest you do so.